# How can I index SQL Server string values for optimized wildcard searching from the left?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-like

I have a string "key" which I need to store in a SQL Server database column. This key is a  dot-delimited list of tokens, of any size. Examples:

```
keanu
2016.sucked
foo.bar.baz
the.cake.is.a.lie
```

I will need to search for rows by any collection of tokens *from the left*. So, I might want to find all tokens that *start*:

```
foo
foo.bar
foo.bar.baz
```

(Obviously, that last one is the entire token).

The only way I know how to do this in SQL is with a `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE key LIKE 'foo.%'
```

How bad is this? `LIKE` has a reputation for performance issues, but since I'm always searching from the left end of the string and leaving the right end open-ended -- does that help?

I had a fleeting idea to do something like this:

```
| key         | base1 | base2    | base3       |
|-------------|-------|----------|-------------|
| foo.bar.baz | foo.  | foo.bar. | foo.bar.baz |
```

Obviously, I'd have to have N columns for `baseX`, which is awful, but there's no doubt it would be fast.

Assuming I use a simple `VARCHAR` field, is there a way to index this field to make it acceptable when I get a million rows of data in here?

Comment: Just create an nonclustered index on it and you'll get ordered scans, as long as the '%' is on the righthand side. The idea of creating n columns is bad on many levels, so better forget it right now.

Comment: If you use `key like 'foo.%'` then an index on `key` *can* be utilized. It's only when you have a leading wildcard that it becomes non-SARGable

Comment: **2016.sucked** lol ;)

Comment: "of any size" is a problem. To index it it must be max 900 bytes.

Comment: @MartinSmith - So what will happen when my first index key value is of 100 bytes and second is of 950 bytes and am searching for first key value index scan or seek ?

Comment: @prdp are you talking about a composite index? You won't be able to insert  values that would lead to a key of 1050 bytes. The insert will fail.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I think I misunderstood. What you meant by *index it it must be max 900 bytes*

Comment: The index key, taking into account all columns can't be over 900 bytes.

Comment: I can live with a 900-byte limit. Realistically, no key would be over 150 bytes or so, but it's good to know about the limitation. I can account for it. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Never know this.. Thanks bro. For Clustered Index max size is 900 bytes and for Non clustered Index is 1700 bytes

Comment: @Prdp only from 2016 on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/04/26/increased-nonclustered-index-key-size-with-sql-server-2016/

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not bad, since you don't have the wildcard at the beginning of search string which would make the query non-sargable. It has to scan through all the pages to find the result since the first character in key value itself is not known.

But in your case, The key value intermediate nodes can be found from the root of the B-tree since we know the starting characters. Creating a `Non clustered Index` on `key` column should help you. The below query is still sargable

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE key LIKE 'foo.%'
```